# Possibile ways to charge a mobile in a train

Tags: comfort

Isn't there any easier way to charge your mobile in a train rather than waking at night for the normal charging point?
  Please note that the train is superfast, e.m.u, passenger train.
What are the illegal or dangerous methods to be avoided for charging mobile as per question?

Comment: What do you mean by "waking at night"? Do you have ordinary electric sockets available? Why the focus on illegal methods?

Comment: @holroy during day there is a lot of  crowd in the socket on sleeper class compartments.There are only two charging points at either ends.People tend to drive batteries on unnecessary chatting, music etc.One easy way usually used is waiting at night for the socket to be free like an owl and charging the mobile.

Comment: One must know what is illegal in this case so that one could know why so it is illegal and how it can affect us otherwise I dont find it illegal if wire is poking out of any removed fan corner and there is a possibility to connect them before complaing to authorities that it may do any harm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Dawnkeeper](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/7573/4490) suggest your safest bet is to use use a power bank or portable fuel charger, but if you want to use the electricity already on the train you your best bet is to locate one which could be slightly hidden and utilise this one. I.e. maybe there is lights in your compartment attached to a socket, or a socket in the bath room (if you have one), underneath the seat, behind a panel (slightly more illegal perhaps).

If no hidden sockets are to be found, or if all are occupied, you could bring your own multi-outlet/power strip/extension cord and disconnect the previous appliance and then reconnect that and your charger in addition. This could even provide another socket (or two) for other in same predicament.

[image: //commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Extensioncord.jpg]

Touching illegal you could argue that you have the option to disconnect switches or lamp bulbs and connect two wires to these and use that as a makeshift socket, but I would strongly advise against any such hacks as you are aboard  a moving train which shifts around which adds to the danger of tampering with live electricity and increases the risks of short circuiting and hurting your self and others.

Comment: extension cord is a good idea but removing lights is not that easy as it is bolted within cases on top and I dont think one could open it without getting caught.

Comment: That is why I wrote "attached to a socket". Do _not_ tamper with fixed devices not connected via plugs to sockets.

Answer (score 1):

You could acquire a [portable fuel cell charger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_cell#Other_applications) or a [power bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_charger#Powerbank).

Fuel Cell chargers usually need longer to charge a phone as they have to produce the energy on the fly, but with enough fuel you have almost endless recharges available.

Power banks are a one-time solution as they will have to be recharged after use, but supply their reserves faster.

Comment: I am not satisfied I can also use mojo.moreovere it is quite luxurious.why not utilising the electricity of train.

Comment: Because you stated that you don't want to?

Comment: i didnt stated that i would not like using train electricity.

Comment: Usually the only legal and non-dangerous way to get to a trains electricity is some charging station or public plug. Your question is written in a way to exclude these.

Comment: okay you can tell any possibilities i may edit my question

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to look for free sockets on A.C compartments compromising with individuals or looking for empty tier.The other individual may not know whether this is your berth or not in the tier.
Possible security concerns are there but with partner it is safe.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there are no way to charge your phone fast enough without using of built-in AC sockets if they are present in train.

Passenger trains may have an AC socket for electric razors, at toilet. If you are lucky man and your train has AC socket and if your phone supports fast(quick) charge, you will have enough time to increase your battery level for 10-20% from 0, while you are in toilet, until next man who wants the toilet will start knocking. You also may use AC splitter and charge simultaneously your phone and your power bank.

Another way is to try to use the USB hand crank dynamo charger (very cheap, easy to buy), but it produces too small power and too big noise for regular using.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to a power bank: you can get power banks and chargers that contain a solar panel. Place the solar panel against a window (preferably a sunlit window).